# How to change main background color in VUE (Visual Understanding Environment)?

Tags: linux, mind-mapping

How to change main background color in [VUE](http://vue.tufts.edu/) (Visual Understanding Environment) ?

When I try to change main background color via `RIGHT CLICK -> Map info -> Info -> Background` - background color does not changing. Is it because I'm not registered user or what ?

I must login for changing background color ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this [trick](http://vue.tufts.edu/help/background-image.cfm).

If something will wrong with first link  - https://gfycat.com/FragrantConfusedHoatzin

[image: add]